# Display recipients name instead of mail address in MFMailComposer

Tags: iphone, ios7, mfmailcomposer

Is it possible to display or show the recipient name in Recipient field instead of the email address. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266518/mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-with-recipient-display-name-as-well-as-email-address) reference but doesn't understand what is done.
Can anyone guide for above. Is there any way to display name instead of email address.

Comment: Did you try the code shown?

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution from the question itself.

```
@"My Name <myname@example.com>"
```